# OSErr -50 on ExtAudioFileOpenURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

The following code:

```
ExtAudioFileRef *file = nil;
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"wav"];
OSErr errorCode = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)path, file);
```

leaves file null and errorCode is -50 ("error in user parameter list"). If file is not initialized to nil, like so:

```
ExtAudioFileRef *file;
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address={garbage value of file}).

How am I supposed to do this? I know the path is correct, because it works for playing the sound elsewhere in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this:

```
ExtAudioFileRef file = NULL;
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"beep" withExtension:@"wav"];
OSErr errorCode = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)path, &file);
```